# How to initialize a pointer to a structure in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, initialization

Here is a defined structure `struct structure` in a `class A`.  `Class B` is nested in `Class A`.

```
class A
{
public:    
    struct structure            // the structure I need 
    {
        std::vector <std::vector <float>>         Input;
        std::vector <int>                         Output;
        float                                     ft;   
        B*                                        bb;
    };
private:    
    B             b;
    structure*    pStruct;                
};
```

Now I want to initialize the pointer `pStruct` before I use it.
For example, I use `pStruct->Output.push_back()`.

Comment: The answer depends a great deal on where the actual `struct` is going to be.

Comment: I guess the easiest would be to write a constructor for your struct. When you call "new structure()", the constructor will be called and it could initialize its members.

Comment: best place to initialise anything is in constructor , you should initialise pStruct in A's constructor.

Comment: Why do you need to have it as a pointer member variable at all?

Comment: @WedaPashi, You might see it as C, but even with vector<> ?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight   Sorry. i can not understand what you mean

Comment: @rayallen Valid non-null pointer always refers to something else, which is somewhere in the memory - global, automatic, or dynamic. It could be shared, or it could be exclusive to the instance of your class. It could have a longer or shorter lifetime than the instance of your class, etc. Answers to these questions determine the answer to "how do I initialize a pointer" question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example you can initialize the pointer in the default constructor of the class. Something like

```
class B {};

class A
    {
     public:
         A() : b(), pStruct( new structure() ) { pStruct->bb = &b; }       
         struct structure            // the structure I need 
         {
          std::vector <std::vector <float>>         Input;
          std::vector <int>                         Output;
          float                                     ft; 
          B*                                        bb;
         };
     private:    
          B             b;
          structure*    pStruct;                
    };
```

Comment: Now when I do debug and the codes run to this postion `pStruct->Output.push_back()`  a file is poped:

Comment: @rayallen  I do not see where there is pStruct->Output.push_back()  in the class definition. But in any case it is another question.

Comment: Thank you all the way . The question is complicated.